# cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Here's my code:

```
function makeIframePlayer(newTracks){
     var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
     var iframeSrc="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:trackset:PREFEREDTITLE:";
     var newarr = new Array();
     for(var i=0;newTracks.length;i++){
           newarr.push(newTracks[i].track.id);
       }
    iframeSrc += newarr.join();
    iframe.src = iframeSrc;
    console.log(iframe.src);
}
```

I get an error when im trying to push the track id into the newarray saying that cannot read property track of undefined(i.e. newTracks[i]). But on the contrary it works fine when instead of pushing it in the newarr i just console.log (newTracks[i].track.id), i get all the ids. As seen newTracks is an array of objects which contains ->track->id. Help!

Comment: A simple examination of the value of `i` in the Javascript debugger would have helped you figure out the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loop is malformed:

```
for(var i=0;newTracks.length;i++){
```

should be:

```
for(var i=0;  i<newTracks.length;  i++){
```

Your version of the loop will loop out of range of `newTracks` because it just tests that the `newTracks` array is not empty, which it isn't (independently of how many times you increase *i*).

So when *i == newTrack.length*, you will address an array element that does not exist (is `undefined`) leading to the error you get.

You can find out these types of problems if you would just add `console.log(i, newTrack[i].length, newTrack[i]);` as the first statement in the loop. Then you see how it runs out of bounds...